# contact form 7 character validation

Tags: php, regex, contact-form, hebrew

I'm using CF7 for a landing page, and I need to create costum validation for text fields - name and city - for them to accept only characters and exclude numbers. The difference is that the form will accept characters in foreign language, Hebrew, and all the guides online are for English text only. 
right now my form look like this:

```
  <center>
    [text* your-name text-727 placeholder "שם מלא"]

    [tel* your-phone tel-356 minlength:9 maxlength:10 placeholder "טלפון"]

    [text* your-age text-727 placeholder "עיר"]

    [tel* your-city tel-356 minlength:2 maxlength:2 placeholder "גיל"]

    [submit "צור קשר!"]
```

How can I validate the input for "name" and "city"?

Comment: You tag wordpress which is a `PHP` CMS so here is reference reading on that specific language: [PHP multibyte strings](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mbstring.php)

Comment: what regex patterns have you tried so far before asking SO? (also as a note - `<center>` got deprecated did it not??)

Comment: I have yet to include any regex, since they mostly suitalbe for the English alphabet. <center> is working fine for me at the moment..

Comment: @EladLavy `<center>` will work still, but after X more browser versions, it will be removed entirely, to future-proof your work I recommend finding an alternative (like using `text-align: center;` with css) and then regarding the patterns, you can google alphabet character only regex (e.g. I think it's something like `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/` but my memory could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

I made an example that can get you started. I'm adding it as an image because the LTR enforcement in StackOverflow (and indeed most Regex testers) completely ruins the regular expression's order):

[image]

- Start at the beginning of the line.
- Search for a minimum of two letters between א and ת (since there are no names/cities in Hebrew with less than two letters).
- Since the user might specify their family name as well we add an optional check for a space followed by another string with at least two letters between א and ת.
- And then we end the string.

This Regex is also good for most cities in Israel, since it is uncommon for them to be comprise of more than two words (except for unusual places like מודיעין מכבים רעות).